# why time.asctime(time.gmtime()) ignores GMT?

Tags: python, time, gmt

I want to get my current time and using

```
from time import *
asctime(gmtime())
```

for this.

However, I get the GMT+0 time instead of my local time which is GMT+3:

```
...$ ipython
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.


In [1]: from time import *; asctime(gmtime())
Out[1]: 'Tue Jul  2 12:02:06 2019'

In [2]:                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? 
...$ date
Tue Jul  2 15:02:12 IDT 2019
...$
```

How to adjust the time to my local time without manually changing the tuple returned from `gmtime()`?

Comment: change asctime to localtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.localtime

> time.localtime([secs])
>
> Like gmtime() but converts to local time. If
>   secs is not provided or None, the current time as returned by time()
>   is used. The dst flag is set to 1 when DST applies to the given time.